# Windows 10 System State Backup wbadmin command errors out with "The specified backup storage location has the shadow copy storage on another volume."?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I'm running a system state backup on a Windows 10 system via bareos...

Before and after the backup, the system state backup is run on the client machine, but mine keeps failing before the backup completes.  The target partition is not full; and this is a fresh Windows 10 PRO OEM installation.

The machine has 4 partitions:

- A 15GB Factory Recovery Partition ( PQSERVICE, no letter ) (gets backed up)
- A 100MB SYSTEM RESERVED Partition ( SYSTEM RESERVED), no letter) (not backed up)
- A 160GB NTFS (C:) (gets backed up)
- A 58GB wbadmin_backup_space (F:) (target of the backup)

I use the following command in a `.bat` script to back it up

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:f: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

and afterwards I clear the backup off the partition with another `.bat` file:

```
rmdir f:\WindowsImageBackup /s /q
```

The `wbadmin` command fails:

I get the following error at the end of the backup:

```
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: Creating a backup of volume PQSERVICE (15.00 GB), copied (0%).
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: Creating a backup of volume PQSERVICE (15.00 GB), copied (100%).
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: Summary of the backup operation:
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: ------------------
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: 
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: The backup operation stopped before completing.
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: The backup operation stopped before completing.
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: Log of files successfully backed up:
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup-23-12-2016_22-37-32.log
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: 
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: ClientBeforeJob: The specified backup storage location has the shadow copy storage on another volume.
23-Dec 22:41 leeand00-pc-fd JobId 217: Error: Runscript: ClientBeforeJob returned non-zero status=253. ERR=Unknown error
23-Dec 22:41 lamp-dir JobId 217: Fatal error: Bad response to RunBeforeNow command: wanted 2000 OK RunBeforeNow
, got 2905 Failed RunScript
```

I saw [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-system-image-backup-0x80780038-error/c8376bf9-8bad-4c87-9ebf-1620be550aa5) that I needed to change the system protection settings to fix the error, and so I did the following:

1. In any explorer window, right click and select: `This PC -> Properties`
2. Click `System protection`
3. Then in the `System protection` window, I noted that the PQSERVICE partition had protection set to `Off` and so I set it to `On`
4. Restarted the machine...
5. Tried the backup again...and got the same error message and result.

However, it still errors out...with the same error message.  Is there anything that can be done to get this `wbadmin` system state backup command to work correctly?

Also, if it is of any relevance I get the following in my error and backup logs:

```
Backup of volume \\?\Volume{924cde0a-0000-0000-0000-10c003000000}\ succeeded.

Backup of volume C: succeeded.

Backup of volume \\?\Volume{924cde0a-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\ succeeded.
```

**C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup-23-12-2016_22-37-32.log**

**Backup_Error-23-12-2016_22-37-32.log** *(this file is just blank)*

Comment: Does the wbadmin command just return the wrong value for bareos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the error message from wbadmin `The specified backup storage location has the shadow copy storage on another volume.` indicates that the volume on which I was doing the backing up on needed to have system protection turned on.

To fix this in Windows 10:

1. Right click on `This PC` and select `Properties`
2. In the resulting `System` window, in the left hand corner, click `System protection`
3. Select the volume on which you are creating your Windows System State (Windows 7) backups.
4. Click the `Configure...` button.
5. In the resulting `System Protection for <volume-name> (DriveLetter:)` dialog,

   1. Click the `Turn on system protection` dialog box.
   2. And if you find you need to, decrease the `Max Usage:`
   3. Also if you end up with an error about free disk space when actually running the backup, you either need to make the partition larger, or click the `Delete` button to clean up any restore points (provided that this volume/drive is ONLY for backups).